Unable to obtain the underlying type of `enum Type : uint8_t`, which should have been `uint8_t`
I don't understand what (underlying) type my enum really gets.. I'm serializing data to a byte buffer and I would prefer to know what I'm really writing..
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

enum Whatever : uint8_t
{
    first = 1,
    second
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(Whatever) << std::endl; // 1, OK
    std::cout << (std::is_same<Whatever, uint8_t>::value       ? "true" : "false") << std::endl; // false, wait what!?
    std::cout << (std::is_same<Whatever, unsigned char>::value ? "true" : "false") << std::endl; // false, also?
    std::cout << (std::is_same<Whatever, int>::value           ? "true" : "false") << std::endl; // false, ...

// EDIT, as per comments; this should have returned true, but it does not.
    std::cout << (std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type<Whatever>, uint8_t> ? "true" : "false, using std::underlying_type") << std::endl; // false
}

... prints,
1
false
false
false
false, using std::underlying_type

.. so what is it really?
Using GCC 8.5.0.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

As a note, you can use std::is_same_v<T, U> as the shorter version of std::is_same<T, U>::value, and you can use std::boolalpha to print booleans for you so you don't have to manually select the right string literal. And on newer compilers, std::print (like fmt::print) already does the right thing: https://godbolt.org/z/G51915Wcd

what makes you think that Whatever is the same as uint8_t? It isn't. It only has the size of uint8_t

The type of a C++ enum is the enum itself. and Underlying type of a C++ enum in C++0x and you can use std::underlying_type<Whatever> as explained in this answer of one of the dupes.

https://godbolt.org/z/j5qnsrfrE

@MarekR your code example prints false on my system, GCC 8.5.0, if that matters.

@Wololo https://godbolt.org/z/975KxeoMz

@MarekR, thanks. I concur that it works on godbolt, and what everyone comments, but when I copy your example, compiles and runs it on my system it still fails and prints false. I give up.

@Wololo, std::underlying_type<Whatever> is different than std::underlying_type_t<Whatever>.  You want the one with _t (which is the same as std::underlying_type<Whatever>::type)

@MarkB Geeeez, I removed the _t because it didn't compile, but with ::type it does, and it returns true correctly. You've no idea how many hours I've wasted on this crap, thank you! Now, if only I could delete the post, but Barry prevents it with his answer.

The type of Whatever is Whatever - it's a distinct type from every other type.
If you want the underlying type of Whatever, as the question asks, that's spelled std::underlying_type_t<Whatever>. That type is uint8_t, which is what you specified it to be.

This is still returns false for me, regardless of if I'm using std::is_same<>::value or std::is_same_v<>. I have GCC v8.5.0

If you upvoted the Q, please remove the upvote so that I may delete it as the community clearly stamps it as a dupe.

@Wololo You don't delete duplicate questions - duplicate questions still provide value to the community because people can find the dupe and track that back to the original. Also in this case, I'm unimpressed with the answers to the linked dupes anyway.

@Wololo And huh? It definitely is true.

Yes is it did correctly return true, eventually when I stopped messing up the _t within std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<Whatever>, uint8_t> - so it was a typo error, really.

No, I disagree. According to the help center page duplicates may be allright, but the down-votes are independent from close-votes and signals low-quality, and thus I believe for the greater good of SO that this post should be removed. If your answer's better than on the other posts, then you should post your answer there.
